# Get number of items on current page based on current position and total items

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a long list of items which are displayed 10 items per page. All I know is the currently selected line number (between 1 and total items, not 1-10 within current page) and the total number of items. I need to calculate how many items are on the current page.

For example, 12 items total, selected line = 11, so there would be 2 items on the page (and it's on page 2)

If the line was 3, the answer would be 10, as it's on page 1, a full page.

Here is my code, which doesn't work. I can get the remainder, but can't seem to figure out the first half. I'm sure there's some obvious answer with a function I'm not using

```
private int NumberOfItemsOnPage()
{
    int itemsOnPage = 0;

    if (CurrentCursorPosition + 10 <= TotalItems)
    {
        itemsOnPage = 10;
    }
    else
    {
        itemsOnPage = TotalItems % 10;
    }

    return itemsOnPage;
}
```

Comment: selected line means `CurrentCursorPosition`?

Comment: `return (TotalItems / 10) > (CurrentCursorPosition / 10) ? 10 : CurrentCursorPosition % 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to divide your problem into two smaller problems.
First problem would be to find out in which page is the item you are positioned.

```
const int PAGE_SIZE = 10;
int currentItemPage = (currentItemPosition / PAGE_SIZE) + 1;
```

The second problem would be to find out how many full pages you've got.

```
int fullPages = totalItems / PAGE_SIZE;
```

And finally, if the `currentItemPage` is within the `fullPages`, that means that your currentItem is in a page with `PAGE_SIZE` items, and if not, it's in the last page with the reminder items.

```
int itemsInCurrentItemPage = currentItemPage <= fullPages ? PAGE_SIZE : totalItems % PAGE_SIZE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all indexes are 0-based:

```
var firstItemOnPage = currentCursorPosition / 10 * 10;
return (totalItems < firstItemOnPage + 10) ? totalItems - firstItemOnPage : 10;
```

(Just a sketch, I'm sure there's a mistake somewhere. This needs some unit-testing.)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, you need integer division:

```
private int NumberOfItemsOnPage(int currentPosition, int totalItems, int itemsPerPage = 10)
{
    int currentPage = currentPosition / itemsPerPage + 1;
    int maxPage = totalItems  / itemsPerPage + 1;
    int itemsOnPage = currentPage == maxPage ? totalItems / itemsPerPage : itemsPerPage;
    return itemsOnPage;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd try this:

```
return (TotalItems / 10) > (CurrentCursorPosition / 10) ? 10 : CurrentCursorPosition % 10
```

If the number of times `TotalItems` has `10` in it is bigger than the number of times `CurrentCursorPosition` has `10` in it, this means you're not on the last page - and return 10. Else, return `CurrentCursorPosition % 10` ...